# Keep showing the tooltips in telerik's radgrid

Tags: javascript, asp.net, css, telerik, radgrid

I have a radgrid that displays some (normal) tooltips for headers and cell content.

Take for example the header tooltip for this column:

```
<telerik:GridBoundColumn 
            HeaderText="<%$ Resources:IFW_Global, FamilyName  %>" HeaderTooltip="<%$ Resources:IFW_Global, FamilyNameTtip  %>" UniqueName="column" 
            AllowFiltering="False" DataField="LastName"
</telerik:GridBoundColumn>
```

And a data cell tooltip, set in code behind:

```
Dim item As GridDataItem = CType(e.Item, GridDataItem)
item("DocumentTypeCode").ToolTip = "customdoctooltip"
```

The tooltips stays visible for only about 5 seconds on mouseover and then it dissapears.

I want all the tooltips to remain visible onmouseover without dissapearing.
How would I do this? I'm looking for a simple solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved this by adding this RadToolTipManager to my masterpage:

```
<telerik:RadToolTipManager ID="RadToolTipManager1" runat="server" Position="BottomRight" AutoTooltipify="true" AutoCloseDelay="0" OffsetY="10">
</telerik:RadToolTipManager>
```

**AutoTooltipify="true"** converts the standard tooltips to radTooltips.
**AutoCloseDelay="0"** gets me the behaviour that I want.

Answer (score 1):

here is some information.  I used to use Telerik a ton and I went straight to their forums when I had a question.  They are quick to answer.  I just searched your question on Telerik and found [this](http://www.telerik.com/forums/tooltip-display):

> you can set the AutoCloseDelay property to 0 which will prevent the
>   tooltip from hiding after an interval.

Comment: This would work if you have a RadToolTipManager with AutoTooltipify=true that will convert the regular tooltips from your browser to RadToolTip instance. If you do not - you are stuck with the browser toolips implementation and they will disappear after some amount of time (which is what the AutoCloseDelay property of the RadToolTip emulates).